# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' . Getting error at print(filename.read())

Tags: python

Currently learning Python using "Learn Python 3 the Hard Way". I'm at exercise 17 and trying to apply the knowledge to my own project while also completing the exercises.

The script is supposed to read 3 lines from a file, then write over the contents of the file and it's then supposed to display the new contents. Instead I get this error.

```
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'**
```

I get the error at line 70 here.

```
print(filename.read())
```

Here's all my code.

```
from sys import argv

script, fname = argv

# This variable just defines what the prompt should look it when
# a user is asked for input.
prompt=(" >>> ")

#This is just a greeting to myself.
print(f"""
-------------------------------------------

Hi {fname}!

If that's not your name you must have entered something else on the terminal.

This is a test project. I will enter in new things I learn to make
sure I'm committing them to memory. Please comment things so I don't
forgot what I'm doing. 

-------------------------------------------
""")

# This will ask the user to input the name of the file
# It will then confirm the filename.
# It will save the open(filename) command to the openFile variable
# Then I print the openFile variable using read()

print("What is the name of your sample file?",end='')
filename=input(prompt)

print(f"\nYou entered {filename} as the name of your file.\nHere are the contents of that file.\n")
openFile=open(filename)

print(openFile.read())

# This will close the variable which "filename" was assigned to but I don't
# think it actually closes the file.

openFile.close()

# This closes the file. I'm not certain if this is the right way to do it
# This might actually close the variable. Not the file. Tomato tomatoe?

# Here's the rest of your project
print(f"""

Great job so far {fname}! So we're going to work on writing to the file.

This will be tricky!

You will be asked to enter 3 lines of text. This will overwriting the existing data.

""")

# Here I'm going to assign filename to a variable called "target"
# I could use truncate to erase the contents of the file but I've read
# that simply opening a file in write mode will accomplish the same thing.

target = open(filename,'w')
line1 = input("Enter line 1:")
line2 = input("Enter line 2:")
line3 = input("Enter line 3:")
target.write(f"line\nline2\nline3")
target.close()


print(f"Great! You've updated {filename}!\nHere's the new content you entered\n")

# THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS OCCURING. NOT SURE WHY
print(filename.read())



print(f"Hi {fname}! What is your last name?",end='')
lname=input(prompt)

print(f"Hello {fname} {lname}! What is your address?",end='')
address=input(prompt)

print("What is your phone number?",end='')
phone=input(prompt)

val =input("Enter any value:")
print(f"You entered {val}.") #https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-input-in-python/

print("What is your age?",end='')
age=input(prompt)
```

Comment: `filename` contains the file name, it is NOT the file descriptor

Answer (score 3):

You have to open it, and read from file descriptor, not filename.
As you did it with

```
openFile=open(filename)

print(openFile.read())
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally got it to work. Please help me understand if this was wrong. I kept trying to do this.

`target = open(filename,"w")`
`print(target.read())`

but I think the issue here was that I was trying to print a variable that was intended for writing to a file. Can you confirm that is wrong?

I got something like this to work

`target = open(filename,"w")`
`print(target.read())`
'printFile = open(filename,"r")`
`print(printFile.read())`

Answer (score 2):

The `filename` variable contains only the file's name, it isn't the file descriptor, you did it nicely before using `openFile` and `target` variables.

---

So do the same for the 3rd, but best : use the `with` syntax, that auto-closes the file when the `with` block is ended

```
print("What is the name of your sample file?", end='')
filename = input(prompt)

print(f"\nYou entered {filename} as the name of your file.\nHere are the contents of that file.\n")
with open(filename) as fic:
    print(fic.read())

# ...

line1 = input("Enter line 1:")
line2 = input("Enter line 2:")
line3 = input("Enter line 3:")
with open(filename, "w") as fic:
    print(fic.read())
    fic.write(f"line\nline2\nline3")

# ...

print(f"Great! You've updated {filename}!\nHere's the new content you entered\n")
with open(filename) as fic:
    print(fic.read())
```